# How to find and fix a Rails and Couchbase memory leak

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, caching, couchbase

I have the following test code:

```
def loop_bucket_gets
    bucket = Couchbase::Bucket.new({:node_list => ['xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8091', 'yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:8091'],
                                    :bucket => 'Foo',
                                    :pool => 'default',
                                    :expires_in => 1.day,
                                    :default_format => :marshal,
                                    :key_prefix => '_foo'
                                   })

    i = 0
    loop do
      begin
        i += 1
        bucket.get "ABC#{i}"
      rescue ::Couchbase::Error::Base => e
        nil
      end
    end
  end
```

When I execute this in the Rails console the memory leaks.

I'm using:

- couchbase 1.3.10 gem
- libcouchbase 2.4.3

I created an issue at https://www.couchbase.com/issues/browse/RCBC-187

Comment: I think you need an end condition for the loop.

Comment: @AlejandroBabio This is test code, I use it to confirm that memory keeps growing thus I mustn't stop the loop.

Comment: Look here: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-ruby-client/blob/324b11ae73934238ab255eaf4f1cd6dab6a239fc/ext/couchbase_ext/get.c#L229

Comment: Easy, without any debugger or IDE: https://github.com/couchbase/couchbase-ruby-client/blob/324b11ae73934238ab255eaf4f1cd6dab6a239fc/ext/couchbase_ext/get.c#L251 ctx initialized, used, but haven't cleared after all.

Comment: @LazarusLazaridis You created a task and reported an issue in Couchbase, and it is currently in RESOLVED state, did you get your answer?

Comment: how do you know it leaks memory?

Comment: Growing memory use in an endless loop is not a "memory leak." A leak is when freed memory is never returned to the system. That is not your problem; your problem is that allocated memory never goes out of scope and therefore can't be garbage collected.

Comment: This is Ruby's memory allocation working as designed.

Comment: you need to give more time in between iteration so that it give time to garbage collector to free up memory and if there are other memory issues you get time to focus on it.
you can add
 sleep 0.01 before rescue in your loop and try again. hope it works.

Answer (score 1):

There is no terminating condition in your loop so it's going to run forever and cause the memory issue you mentioned. You should add a relevant `break` condition in your loop and test if it resolves the issue.

```
def loop_bucket_gets
    bucket = Couchbase::Bucket.new({:node_list => ['xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8091', 'yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy:8091'],
                                    :bucket => 'Foo',
                                    :pool => 'default',
                                    :expires_in => 1.day,
                                    :default_format => :marshal,
                                    :key_prefix => '_foo'
                                   })

    i = 0
    loop do
      begin
        i += 1
        bucket.get "ABC#{i}"
        break if YOUR_TERMINATING_CONDITION
      rescue ::Couchbase::Error::Base => e
        nil
      end
    end
  end
```